# TCP: already connected socket got reset by kernel?

Tags: linux, tcp

Does anybody have an idea on why a socket which had already been connected and tranceiving data  was reset by kernel? 
10.103.143.101 was downloading data from network.
Check the tcpdump bellow. Thanks!

```
26110       14:58:44.369708     122.11.56.106 10.103.143.101        HTTP         Continuation or non-HTTP traffic  
26112       14:58:44.371356     122.11.56.106 10.103.143.101        HTTP         Continuation or non-HTTP traffic  
26113       14:58:44.372088     10.103.143.101        122.11.56.106 TCP  42421 > 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=9062171 Win=36787 Len=0 TSV=253488 TSER=1943531727  
26115       14:58:44.373919     10.103.143.101        122.11.56.106 TCP  42421 > 80 **[RST, ACK]** Seq=1 Ack=9062171 Win=36864 Len=0 TSV=253488 TSER=1943531727
```

Comment: Most likely the client exited or closed its socket.

Comment: Is this your client/server App, did you check for errors on send/recieve on your code? If it is not in code in your code but in SSH/Apache/Samba/etc perhaps the question should be go to superuser or serverfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a myriad of things and it is impossible to tell from just that trace. A few possibilities include the remote host could have been shutdown, the program on the host could have been shut down, a proxy could have shut it down, etc.

Do you have access to the remote host? If you do perhaps you can view some log files from the application on that end? Hope that helps.